# Internal Error occurred Firebase Custom Token Authentication

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-authentication

I was using Firebase custom token to authenticate user. When I run the application with Android Naugate it works fine but when I try to authenticate with another phone with android version 5.1.1 it gives me error like this

```
com.google.firebase.FirebaseException: An internal error has occurred. [ null ]
    at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzdxm.zzao(Unknown Source)
    at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzdwn.zza(Unknown Source)
    at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzdxx.zzap(Unknown Source)
    at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzdya.onFailure(Unknown Source)
    at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzdxo.onTransact(Unknown Source)
    at android.os.Binder.execTransact(Binder.java:453)
```

and sometimes it gives me error like this

```
com.google.firebase.FirebaseNetworkException: A network error (such as timeout, interrupted connection or unreachable host) has occurred.
```

Code calling Firebase is as follows:

```
firebaseAuth.signInWithCustomToken(customToken)
            .addOnCompleteListener(this, new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
                @Override
                public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
                    if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                        // Sign in success, update UI with the signed-in user's information
                        Log.d("SignIn", "signInWithCustomToken:success");
                        FirebaseUser user = firebaseAuth.getCurrentUser();
                        userId=user.getUid();
                        Log.e("current User is",user.getUid());

                    } else {
                        // If sign in fails, display a message to the user.
                        Log.e("Firebase Error",""+task.toString());
                        Log.e("Sign iN failed", "signInWithCustomToken:failure", task.getException());
                        Toast.makeText(ChatActivity.this, "Authentication failed.",
                                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        /// updateUI(null);
                    }
                }
            });
```

Please help me to resolve this error. Thank you

Comment: Maybe you can show the code calling firebase ?

Comment: Please check the question, I have edited the code and added the code calling the firebase.

Comment: yes I did and I have no problem while implementing other sign in methods. This problem is occurring only with custom token authentication.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue in JS, the error comes out of signin function (signInWithCustomToken) you must have provided a wrong token.
The user is created on the firebase cloud when you sign in with a generated token.
Provide more details about your token generation.